# Give an integer where the class modulo 840 is an element of maximum order of (840Z)^x

Tags: group-theory

I started the question by proving that (840Z)<sup>×</sup> is isomorphic to (2Z)<sup>4</sup> × 3Z × 4Z.

Then I found that the maximum value of order of the elements in (840Z)^× is 12.

How do I proceed from here ? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: $$840=2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\;$$ ...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to ask that it be congruent to $2\bmod 5$ and to be congruent to $2\bmod 7$. Then in order for $2^a$ to be $1\bmod 5$ and $1\bmod 7$ we need for $a$ to be a multiple of $4$ and $3$.

A good example of such a number is $2$. By the way good job doing the previous part, I think that was the hardest.